# How to draw a wall- solidbox with OpenGL-es?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to make a wall or a solid box like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]
That you can see,I have a window on the wall. Currently, I created 4nodes and integrate them to make the window, and add them to a parent node. But I cannot change the texture, only color.
So I want to draw a wall like this, that mean how to create the list of vertices to make it.
But I dont know how to do that.
Can anyone point me a way?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to figure out how to make a wall with a window as one polygonal object.

Make it out of four separate pieces, like this:

```
  AAAAAAAAA
  BBB   CCC
  BBB   CCC
  DDDDDDDDD
```

Unless you leave gaps between the pieces, it will look like a wall with a window.

Comment: yes,currently i'm doing this way,make 4 pieces,but when i change the texture,they cannot consistent,that you can see on this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozir2rzgwkqvoun/photo.PNG

Comment: You need to assign correct texture coordinates to the vertices.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, you need to not have the entire texture covering each of the four pieces. If the "B" piece is half as wide as the "A" piece, it's texcoord should range from (0,0) to (0.5, 0.5) or something like that. Assigning texture coords to pieces is often a painful part of making artwork for games. I'd suggest creating your wall polygons via a function which calculates their texture coordinates based on their dimensions.